# How to change an image link based on content in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to put a image on my page (page1) that is a link to another page (page2), but I want the image that is displayed to be one of two possible images, based on the content of page2.

Page2 in this case is a wiki page that reports current status. If there are no problems to report, the image on page1 will be green in color. If there are problems listed, the image will be red.

My plan for accomplishing this is to use the html comment tags to embed either `<!--STATUSRED-->` or `<!--STATUSGREEN-->` on my wiki page. Then I figured I could use javascript, Jquery or something similar to check for the presence of my comment and alter the image on page1 accordingly. I am just not sure HOW exactly to do this.

I am also open to other ideas. Whatever solution I come up with, it has to be simple for the wiki user to change without requiring the user to change page1 (which is not part of the wiki).

**UPDATE:**

What I finally ended up doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    statusCheck();
    setInterval(statusCheck,300000);
}

function statusCheck() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "path/to/wiki/MainPage.ashx",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $('#statusImage').attr('src', function() {
                if ($(html).find("#statusGreen").length)
                {
                    return '/images/green.gif';
                }
                else
                {
                    return '/images/red.gif';
                }
            });         
        },
        error: function(request,status, error) {
            $('#statusImage').attr('src', '/images/red.gif');
        }       
    });
}
```

and then on the wiki page I just change the id attribute on the div in question to either 'statusGreen' or 'statusRed' like so:

```
<div id="statusGreen">
<font size="5" color="green">No issues to report.</font>
</div>
```

and the image I want to change gets a 'statusImage' id:

```
<img id="statusImage" width="95" height="95" border="0" />
```

Comment: How is page2 determining this status? Is that being done on the server? You could just point at a single image on page1, and have the page2 script change it to red or green (e.g. replace the file on the server with the appropriate color)

Comment: The status being reported on page2 is manually updated by the wiki users. They would have to manually change the comment tag and then the script would have to check this tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very wasteful as you get all wiki page's content to just check for the presence of a single word, anyway, here's how to do it:

```
<div id="hidden_container" style="display: none;"></div>
<img src="" id="wikistatus"/>

function set_status() {
  var status_image = 'images/green.gif';
  $('#hidden_container').empty();
  $('#hidden_container').load('path/to/wiki.html #status', function() {
    var status = $('#hidden_container').text();
    var is_green = status.indexOf('<!--STATUSGREEN-->');
    if(is_green === false) status_image = 'images/red.gif';
    $('#wikistatus').attr('src', status_image);
    setTimeout('set_status();', 5000); // execute again in 5 seconds
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  set_status();
});
```

In wiki.html make sure you wrap the status code in a container with `status` as id:

```
<div id="status"><!--STATUSGREEN--></div>
```

Comment: Very similar to what I ended up doing, above. I agree with your comments about this being wasteful, but don't see a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To make it a bit easier you could just add a param (if it's possible, depending on how much control you have over the wiki)

`<a href="page2"><img src="page2?image" alt="" /></a>`

And have the wiki page return the correct image directly if the request contains the param "image"

Comment: I don't have as much control over page2 (the wiki) as I do with page1. I would prefer for the switching logic to happen there.